# Ideal Account to use for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

What is the ideal "Log On As" account to use for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express?

Comment: The one with the least amount of privileges that will still achieve desired functionality.  :)

Comment: Seriously, why was this downvoted twice after months of inactivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you're going to access it, in a Domain, Locally, or else. The most secure way is to use Windows Authentication. But if that's not your case, you could user Mixed Authentication and remember a best practice is to create an account with SysAdmin privileges, and disable SA account that is created by default.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

In general, if you can use a windows account, you have greater security. This is not always possible (many ISP situations come to mind), so you have to use SQL security. But determining best account to use depends on context.

If this is for an Application, "sa" is never the answer.